# Accelerate the speed of loop over Pandas groupby

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas

I have a big Data Frame in which contains many subsets. For instance,

```
data = pd.read_csv(src) # I read from file
gr = data.groupby('name') # group data by some criteria
lgr = gr.groups.viewkeys() # find list key
for group in lgr: # let say I have 10000 groups
  __data = gr.get_group(group)
  # do somethings here
  # these works take time
```

I want to accelerate the loop so I tend to use multi_threading. But I wonder if there are another approach? Because if I use threading like code below, I worries many threads read `gr` sametime

```
def run_in_thread(func):
    from functools import wraps
    @wraps(func)
    def run(*k, **kw):
        t = threading.Thread(target=func, args=k, kwargs=kw)
        t.start()
        return t
    return run
@run_in_thread
def group_with_thread(gr, keys):
  # define somethings
group_with_thread(gr, list(keys)[1:5000])
```

Could you please give me any advices? Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think this is going to work, multi-threading isn't a magic bullet... Have you tried [dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it. I am investigating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to put here an approach and it works for me. You can check at https://github.com/josepm/MP_Pandas.

> The basic idea in a multiprocessor group-by/apply is to assign groups
>   resulting from the group-by step to different CPUs. Enabling
>   multiprocessing in a Pandas group-by/apply is interesting if it is
>   generic in the sense that we preserve the syntax and we do not need to
>   rewrite a special apply function code.